# Why Catalina 10.15.7 block JarLauncher when start from .app?

Tags: macos, spring-boot, javafx, macos-catalina, .app

I have My.app correctly working on(starts from two click):

High Sierra 10.13.6

Catalina 10.15.2

but refuse to start on Catalina 10.15.7, it starts than immediately quit.

My.app - it is java application(spring-boot, javaFX) which starts from bash script.
[My.app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHJWn.png)

myJavaFX.jar running properly if I starts from terminal(java -jar myJavaFX.jar), on Catalina 10.15.7.

Do you have any ideas what can block JarLauncher when start from .app? Or else?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem wasn't in versions of MacOS. The problem was in multiple simultaneous starting from one folder, probably due to security issues.